# How to set the TRichedit default paragraph background color

Tags: delphi, winapi, delphi-7

I try to set the `TRichEdit` control default paragraph bg color with this code:

```
//******************************************************************************
class procedure TRichEditUtility.setBGColor( aRE_ : TTNTRichEdit; bgColor_ : cardinal; default_ : boolean = FALSE );
//******************************************************************************
var
  cf: TCharFormat2;
begin
  if ( aRE_ <> NIL ) then
  begin
    fillchar(cf, sizeof(cf), 0);
    cf.cbSize := sizeof( cf );
    cf.dwMask := CFM_BACKCOLOR;
    cf.crBackColor := bgColor_;
    if ( default_ ) then
      aRE_.Perform( EM_SETCHARFORMAT, SPF_SETDEFAULT, lparam(@cf) )
    else
      aRE_.Perform( EM_SETCHARFORMAT, SCF_SELECTION, lparam(@cf) );
  end else
    raise EInvalidInputParameter.create_string( 'TRichEditUtility', 'setBGColor', 'aRE_', CONST_chars_NIL );
end;
```

But the value of the `SPF_SETDEFAULT` constant is unknown!

Can somebody tell me its value? (Or the file name which define its value)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how to resolve this issue, and any issue of this nature.

- Perform a websearch for `SPF_SETDEFAULT`.
- This takes you to the documentation for [`EM_SETCHARFORMAT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774230.aspx).
- That document lists `Richedit.h` as the required header.
- Locate `Richedit.h` in your copy of the Windows SDK and search for `SPF_SETDEFAULT`.
- That search yields this: `#define SPF_SETDEFAULT 0x0004`.
- So in Delphi you define the constant like this: `const SPF_SETDEFAULT = $0004`.

Comment: Of course I found this page. But unfortunatelly I haven't seen the comment about richedit.h. Nevertheless I found richedit.pas in the uses and I've searched that constant in this. But it doesn't contained this.
But now I know it's value and I'm happy with it. Thanks for your answer! ;)

Comment: That's fine. I just wanted to take your through all the steps so that you know how to do this yourself in the future. I think that's better than just telling you that the value is `0x0004`. Which is exactly what you meant by *or the file name which define its value*.

Comment: FYI, `SCF_ALL` - another flag used with `EM_SETCHARFORMAT` (and is defined in Delphi's `RichEdit.pas` unit) - is also defined as 0x0004.  So that seems a conflict that two flags for the same message have the same value. And FWIW, `SPF_SETDEFAULT` is not declared anywhere in the Windows SDK that ships with XE8 (I haven't checked Seattle yet).

Comment: @Remy It's defined in the SDK that MS supply. Don't know where Emba are getting the SDK that they ship with C++Builder.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: They get it from Microsoft.  They usually get what is currently available at the time they are releasing a new IDE, but they do have to customize some of the SDK headers to account for compiler issues. Do we know which SDK introduced the `SPF_SETDEFAULT` define? And BTW, I have seen code that uses `SPF_SETDEFAULT` with `EM_SETPARAFORMAT` instead of `EM_SETCHARFORMAT`, even though it is not documented that way. `SPF_SETDEFAULT` would make more sense in `EM_SETPARAFORMAT` (and would be consistent with the `SPF_` prefix).